# Flights Arriving TO (not From!) an Airport

Tags: france, flight-search-engines

I’m trying to find a list of all flight arriving *to* BIQ on September 1, 2023 — online services allow me to find flight *from* that airport to anywhere, but not to. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this can be done on [flightconnections.com](https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-to-biarritz-biq) with a paid subscription, which allows you to filter by date.  Not 100% sure, though, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It is about future, so timetable may not be stable. Did you look the airport website? It may have some data. You may be able to extract from past (and maybe from media documents, e.g. new flights).

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, each city pair is symmetric: if there’s a flight from A to B there will be a flight from B to A. There are a few more complex situations with triangular flights but they are relatively rare. You can also usually find destinations on the Wikipedia page of the airport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done on KIWI.com by setting the departure location "Europe" and select "direct" only. Turns out that all direct flights BIQ originate in Europe. There appear to be 15 of them on Sep 1.

I strongly recommend booking flights directly with the airline and NOT on kiwi.com who has a particular bad reputation for that sort of thing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Airport website* is the place where you would go for arrivals timetable, updated in the real time. I can imagine that some airports would only have arrivals for the nearest few days. Still does not make this rule any less useful.

As for the general answer for Yandex Timetables service produces a legit looking timetable for arrivals to [BIQ airport for September, 1](https://rasp.yandex.ru/station/9631930/?event=arrival&date=2023-09-01&time=all):
[image: Automated translation of rasp.yandex.ru]

(Yes, it's all in Russian - this has machine translation applied. Their search box for the most part accepts IATA codes, so it's not useless)

The difference from the other answer is that it is a pure timetable, not a connectivity graph or a shopping cart for flights on that day.